# What is the pinout on my K F455P 7An filter?

Tags: filter, datasheet, receiver, amplitude-modulation, ham-radio

[image]

I have a ceramic filter that I'm using for an AM receiver, but I don't know the pins for it. The lettering on it says K F455P 7An. I know that it's a 455 kHz signal filter and I think that it has a bandwidth of 7 kHz. I haven't been able to test it, though, because I don't know the pinout. Looking for datasheets returns nothing helpful. I think that it is made by Murata. Has anyone used this filter before?

In the image shown you can see the front of the filter. There are three pins on the opposite side of this filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a Kyocera part. I found the following datasheet for Kyocera KBF455P. It has a 7 Amp version which is what this would be. http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/40/avx_kbf-322461.pdf

Took a bit to find since it's an obsolete part. Pinout is on the first page of the datasheet, also inserted below (as shown pin 2 is the bottom center pin, pin 3 is above it to the right a bit):

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I could not find a datasheet for this anywhere!